# Merging RTF files?

Tags: java, rtf, fileinputstream

I'm using Java and I need to append, concat, merge or add, whichever is the right term, two .rtf files together in its original format for both rtf files, into one rtf file.  Each of the rtf files are a page long, so I need to create a two page rtf file, from the two files.

I also need to create a page break between the two files, in the new combined rtf file.  I went to MS word and was able to combine the two rtf files together, but that just created a long rtf file with no page break.

I have a code, but it only copies one file to another file in the same way, but I need help on tweaking out this code so I can copy two files into one file

```
  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("old.rtf");
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("new.rtf");

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

  int count;

  while ((count= file.read(buffer)) > 0) 
      out.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

How do I add another FileInputStream object on top of the FileInputStream file, into FileOutputStream out, with a page break between file and object?

I am totally stuck.  I was able to combine the two rtf files with help, but could not keep the original format of the two rtf file into the new one.

I tried the :

```
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("old.rtf");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("new.rtf", true);

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

     int count;
     while ((count= file.read(buffer)) > 0) 
     out.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append), where the old.rtf is suppose to append to new.rtf, but when I do it, the old.rtf is just written into the new.rtf.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the file you wish to add to, use the `FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)` with `append` set to true, then you can add to the new file, rather than over write it.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("old.rtf");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("new.rtf", true);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int count;

while ((count= file.read(buffer)) > 0) 
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

This will append `old.rtf` to `new.rtf`.

You can also do:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("old1.rtf");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("new.rtf");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int count;

while ((count= file.read(buffer)) > 0) 
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);

file.close();

file = new FileOutputStream("old2.rtf");
while ((count= file.read(buffer)) > 0) 
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

That will concatenate `old1.rtf` and `old2.rtf` to the new file `new.rtf`.

Comment: Is there any ways you can elaborate the answer.  It kind of makes sense, but still very lost.  Thank You

Comment: Will Hartung,  I REALLY appreciate your response, and know its right, but I just cannot get my head to understand it.  I try to put it in and does not work for me.  What am i doing wrong??  I am just too new to this and just not getting it.